# Which is the best performance settings to perfom a triple join query

Tags: mysql, groupwise-maximum

Hi everybody I'm working on a personal project but right now i have almost everything done, except for this, i have 2 tables

users

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | john |
| 2 | doe |

bills

| id | month | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | january | paid |
| 2 | february | pending |
| 3 | march | pending |

but i trying to give the user a summary of this information so, which will be the best performance setting

1. doing a triple join query
   e.g.

   **select u.name,a.*,b.*** 

   **from users u** 

   **left join (select id,max(month) as last_month_paid from bills where status='paid') a**

   **on u.id=a.id**

   **left join (select id,min(month) as last_month_pending from bills where status='pending') b**

   **on u.id=b.id**
2. or create 3 database views
   a.paid bill view 
   b.pending bill view
   c.summary view

   thanks for your comments

Comment: views don't do anything to improve performance

Comment: Additionally, there is no association to a given user and bills.  I can see a unique bill id, but no user id for a given bill id.

Comment: Assumin your `month` column is `varchar`, then applying `MAX()` or `MIN()` on this column is nonsense, since April will be always the min value and September will be always the max value.

Comment: I believe that views are more time efficient,    there's no association because I didn't write down, but exist in table and month field it's int

Answer (score 0):

Reformulate this way:

```
select  name,
        ( SELECT  max(month)
            from  bills
            where  status='paid'
              AND  id = u.id )  AS last_month_paid
        ( SELECT  min(month) as last_month_pending
            from  bills
            where  status='pending'
              AND  id = u.id )  AS last_month_pending
    from  users u
```

If you need other columns, it gets more complex.  See that tag I added.